# Sending http POST request to local nodejs Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, client-server, http-post, client-side

I am trying to find a way to send an Http POST with an array of latency data from a client's html page to the node server on localhost.

So far examples I have found instead show only how to set up the GET/POST request on the server side but not how to send POST request from the client to server.

I have no experience in with http requests so any advice or references anyone recommends? 
Just need a push in the right direction :]

My node server needs to be able to receive that array from the client. Here's my server code

```
var http    = require('http')
  , connect = require('connect')
  , io      = require('socket.io');

var app = connect().use(connect.static(__dirname)).use(connect.directory(__dirname));
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(8888);
io = io.listen(server);
```

Comment: The wording in your question is confusing.  Are you trying to send a POST request from the client (a browser or whatever) to the Node server?  Or...if not...what?

Comment: yup & nevermind I was able to work something out

Comment: The confusing part was partially the original wording, but also the fact that you've got a bit of server code here while you are asking about a client-side question.  This makes your question really high-level like "how do I send data to a server?"  Also, there's no routes for POST in your node snippet...but that's a different issue.

Comment: yeah I posted my server code for the 2nd part. I was also unsure if I had set it up correctly to even receive http requests.